# How to send an Email automatically using Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm building an Android Application where the output is a QR Code image. How do I send this image through mail automatically to users email when a button is clicked. (User should not see any Email Interface or activity)
User Email Id is entered in previous activity. Subject will be a default text to all the mails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's libraries for sending email like JavaMail.  The problem is you need a mail server to send them through.  That would require either the user knowing, and trusting you with, the credentials to their smtp server, or you hosting an SMTP server that the app can send mail through.  The first case is unlikely to work, as the user will be unlikely to know that data, and if technical enough to know it unlikely to trust you with it.  In the second case, the odds of your emails being flagged as spam is nearly 100%.  Oh, and you know have to put the password to your email server in the app, meaning its utterly insecure and will be used as a spam relay.

Instead, you should do one of the following:
1)Just launch the user's email app, which already knows all of this info and is properly set up.
2)DOn't send the email client side.  Do it server side.  You'll still have issues being flagged as spam, but at least your server won't be utterly insecure.

Comment: Yeah, but my project is like a public device which will be kept in a public room where people do interact with it to get a data through mail. So, people are not able to use email application from here.

Comment: Then I suggest doing it from the server.  If you try to do it from the client, you'll be putting your email server's info on the device, which is never a good idea.  At the very least make an endpoint to get that info from the server so it isn't saved on the device.